# String concatenation error in shell command

Tags: visual-studio-2010, perl, msbuild, clickonce

I have msbuild command as below

```
my $cmd = "msbuild /v:n /target:clean;publish /p:Configuration=".$buildConfig." \"".$solutionPath."\" /p:OutputPath=" ."\"$outputdir\" /p:SolutionDir="."\"$sourceDir\\";
```

On compilation this s the exact command which looks fine to me. I am not sure why there is a " missing at the end of the line.

```
msbuild /v:n /target:clean;publish /p:Configuration=Release "D:\Projects\Suite\Verify\Manager\source\Project1\Project1.csproj" /p:OutputPath="D:\Repository\Suite\Project1" /p:SolutionDir="D:\Projects\Suite\Verify\
```

Also if I copy the exact text in command line it works without any errors.

But when i run it from a perl script i get the following error

```
(PostBuildEvent target) -> 
 c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3717,9): error MSB3073: The command "copy "D:\Projects\Suite\Verify\ 2>&1\Common\libraries\ABC.NET\ABC9-32.dll" "D:\Projects\Suite\Verify\ 2>&1bin\Release\"" exited with code 1. [D:\Projects\Suite\Verify\Common\source\Plan\Plan.csproj]
```

Here `" 2>&1"` is getting appended from somewhere and i don't how to handle it ?

Basically project1 has a dependency on Plan which has a postbuild event set to copy the file `"ABCpdf9-32.dll"`. Why am i getting this error ? whats the solution. Please help

Comment: Looks to me like you have a missing `"` at the end there, and a backslash that is escaped instead. You know, you can use forward slash in paths in windows to make things easier where escaping is concerned.

Comment: Can you give me the exact command line , which should work ?

Answer (score 1):

The `my $cmd ...` line could be simplified. Rather than concatenating (with `.`) may items, just use interpolation as is done for `$outputdir` and `$sourceDir`. The whole line simplifies to

```
my $cmd = "msbuild /v:n /target:clean;publish /p:Configuration=$buildConfig \"$solutionPath\" /p:OutputPath=\"$outputdir\" /p:SolutionDir=\"$sourceDir\\";
```

Having simplified the line I see that it finishes with a `\\";`, meaning the `SolutionDir` argument has an opening double quote and no closing double quote. Try changing the final `\\` to be `\"` as in this line

```
my $cmd = "msbuild /v:n /target:clean;publish /p:Configuration=$buildConfig \"$solutionPath\" /p:OutputPath=\"$outputdir\" /p:SolutionDir=\"$sourceDir\"";
```